# How really functions WAITFOR statement in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Maybe someone already ask this, but I can't find appropriate answer to this question.

If I have, let's say, following query:

```
SELECT 
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
FROM Table1 AS t1
WAITFOR DELAY '10:00:00'
```

where this query returns around 100000 rows.

Did `WAITFOR` statement waiting 10 hours before telling SQL Server to execute query and produce result or SQL Server execute query immediately and keep result in RAM for 10 hours and then send it over network or just show?

Am I missing here something?

I would appreciate if someone give me real example that prove first or second solution.

I executed next query:

```
SELECT GETDATE()
SELECT GETDATE()
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
```

The result was two dates that were the same. On this basis, I will conclude that SQL Server immediately executes the query and keeps the result for certain time to show, but that made little sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx), the `WAITFOR` command is used to block a statement or transaction for the specified amount of time.  In that case, you'd use it to delay subsequent statements.  In other words, you'd want to execute something *after* the `WAITFOR` command, not before.  Here's a few examples:

The following example executes the stored procedure after a two-hour delay.

```
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '02:00';
    EXECUTE sp_helpdb;
END;
GO
```

The following example executes the stored procedure sp_update_job at 10:20 P.M. (22:20).

```
USE msdb;
EXECUTE sp_add_job @job_name = 'TestJob';
BEGIN
    WAITFOR TIME '22:20';
    EXECUTE sp_update_job @job_name = 'TestJob',
        @new_name = 'UpdatedJob';
END;
GO
```